# Azure API Management Maintenance plan

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, downtime

I had deployed a Azure API Management service in Developer Pricing tier. But it is going into frequent Maintenance plan. So, I changed my pricing tier to Basic. So, How much of downtime will be there after changing the tier? And also, the basic pricing tier denoting 99.95% SLA. Is that means my service's Uptime is 99.5%?

Could anybody give clarification on this?

Comment: Refer the table in this document to understand the downtime according to the SLA percentage- SLA Downtime per week Downtime per month Downtime per year
99% 1.68 hours 7.2 hours 3.65 days
99.9% 10.1 minutes 43.2 minutes 8.76 hours
99.95% 5 minutes 21.6 minutes 4.38 hours
99.99% 1.01 minutes 4.32 minutes 52.56 minutes
99.999% 6 seconds 25.9 seconds 5.26 minutes > Document link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/framework/resiliency/business-metrics

Comment: 99.95% is the availability of the APIM for Basic tier

Comment: Refer this document to improve the Reliability and uptime of APIm instance -https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/high-availability

Answer (score 0):

That is correct but keep in mind that when your service goes to an upgrade or  update the service will be working with half of its capacity so if that is not enough to serve your load to the APIM service you may experience soma availability issue.

The Basic tier can have maximum 2 units each unit has 2 Small VMs which are limited in capacity.